# Strongly typed calls to other microservices in LoopBack v4

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I'm currently evaluating the suitability of LoopBack for a future **microservice**-based project. Moreover, I'm new to LoopBack, so please correct me, if a misunderstood the concepts of Loopback.

At times, you need an aggregator microservice which calls several others. Is it possible to generate a strongly typed *client library stubs* (in the form of a `Service`) analogous to the `lb4 openapi` command?

And if not, what is the point of using TypeScript ([as advertized](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/)), when one has to use pure JavaScript as shown in these examples [(1)](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-openapi/blob/master/README.md) [(2)](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/REST-connector.html)?

Also is there an option to use an OpenAPI spec file from existing services?

It seems to me that this is a 'terra incognita' at this point for LoopBack v4 with TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer of LoopBack.

There are a few things involved here:

1. Communication between microservices - we support REST and gRPC via connectors, such as loopback-connector-openapi and loopback-connector-grpc.
2. As you mentioned, it's on the roadmap to generate service stubs - see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1070#issuecomment-403530459. The `lb4 openapi` command has implemented a lot of logic that can be applied to `lb4 openapi-stub`. Contributions are welcome!
3. You should also check out https://github.com/strongloop/loopback4-example-shopping/pull/268.

Comment: According to the documentation, it`s possible to create the data source from the OpenApi service.
Could you please point me to some instructions or examples of how to create such a data source?